# Did I calculate EBITDA correctly for LAUR?

Tags: corporate-earnings

I struggle to pick out the right numbers from financial reports of publicly traded companies to calculate EBITDA.  I randomly picked the stock LAUR and found this document:

http://s23.q4cdn.com/290406876/files/doc_financials/2019/Q3/10Q.pdf

This [webpage here](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/what-is-ebitda/) says that a formula I can use for EBITDA is

> EBITDA = Net Income + Interest + Taxes + Depreciation + Amortization

From what I can tell, here are the numbers I can pick out from the financial report:

```
Net Income = 877,609 -> on page 4
Interest = -9,552 - 136,438 -> page 4
Tax = -60,677 -> page 4
Depreciation/Amort = -1,029,619 -> page 7  (although I also see 146,284 on page 9, which is a big discrepancy?)
```

So adding up all these values gives us an EBITDA of -$358,677 for the first 9 months of their fiscal year.  Is that correct?  I feel like I did something completely wrong because I have so much trouble picking out the right numbers from financial statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So EBITDA is a measure of how a company is performing without taking into account any of their interest, tax, depreciation, or amortization **expense**. In the case of interest, you took into account both interest expense and interest income. Additionally, for the formula you referenced, you should be *adding* these expenses back to net income, not subtracting. In your case, you're effectively accounting for ITDA twice.

Lastly, as far as amortization/depreciation: the 1,029,619 number is their total accumulated amortization & depreciation. You're trying to find the EBITDA for just this year, so only just this year's amortization & depreciation expense numbers.

EBITDA = 877,609 NI + 136,438 interest + 60,677 tax + 146,282 depre/amort

EBITDA = 1,221,006

Hope this helps!